# Are there any videos of onboard the Apollo Lunar Module while landed on the Moon?

Tags: the-moon, gravity, moonwalking, apollo-program

These would be very worthy videos since there is air in the Lunar Module and they don't wear the heavy spacesuits, so one could see how they behave on the Moon in a breathable atmosphere and without heavy spacesuits.

Comment: One of the issues with the Apollo lunar modules was the were very cramped

Comment: You should try to take a video of two people walking and jumping in a telephone box. Yes, that old box with a telephone when nobody had a mobile phone. "at Earth's atmospheric pressure and density" was impossible, the pressure inside the LM was much lower than on Earth.

Comment: What was the pressure inside the Lunar Module?

Comment: From the NASA quick reference data for the lunar module [pdf](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/LM04_Lunar_Module_ppLV1-17.pdf):

Comment: That would mean about 0.33 atm. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Imagine you were making a movie.  Pretty quickly you'd realize that your mock-up LM would need to have lots of removable panels so that the camera could see from an interesting angle without extreme distortion.  And you'd spend hours planning and preparing each shot.   Needless to say, the real LM didn't have lift-off panels and a camera crew outside with a boom.  Today at best you might be able to put tiny wide-angle cameras all over the interior surfaces and sort out the video later to get at least a little that wasn't a head or elbow blocking a lens; that wasn't really practical then.

Comment: iirc - they were always wearing the suits - certainly on Apollo 11. Perhaps other flights took them off during more extended stays

Comment: I recently did a pretty exhaustive search regarding Apollo 11 images. Found no LEM videos. As for the broken circuit breaker, Aldrin explained, "We discovered during a long checklist recitation that the ascent engine's arming circuit breaker was broken off on the panel. The little plastic pin (or knob) simply wasn't there. This circuit would send electrical power to the engine that would lift us off the moon... We looked around for something to punch in this circuit breaker. Luckily, a felt-tipped pen fit into the slot." I said, somewhere else, he thought he'd broken getting out of his suit.

Comment: For anyone who wants to do an exhaustive search, there's list of all video made on each mission in the Lunar Surface Journals: https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/main.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While not on the lunar surface, it turns out that in-flight footage of donning and removing suits inside the LM during the Apollo 16 mission does exist.

One source is https://www.sciencephoto.com/media/239627/view however the origin is presumably a government document available from other places as well.

The perspective is surprisingly good for cramped quarters, but that's likely in no small part due to the fact that it was shot either through or in the docking tunnel by Ken Mattingly who would remain in the command module when the LM separated to land.  Likely it would have been much harder to capture anything interesting with an unmanned camera located in the cramped confines of the LM itself.

Today we might be able to put little recording webcams all over the interior surfaces and select unblocked shots later, or perhaps even do some sort of synthetic image stitching to combine captures from multiple points.  But even a single wide-angle motion picture camera on the docking tunnel cover would have been a fair amount of complexity; the interesting sights were outside.

Comment: "filmed by Ken Mattingly from the docking tunnel connecting the lander to the Command Module"; this probably helped the perspective a lot.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the video seems to be in time-lapse.

Comment: The frame rate might be a hair slow but it is within the realm of motion video.  If you are seeing a time-lapse effect, perhaps your connection is having issues or the site's software is not working well with your web browser.  Perhaps you can find a source for the original which permits you to download it for offline viewing.

Comment: 16 won't count, strictly speaking, if Mattingly took the film, since by definition, the crew weren't on the lunar surface

Comment: The fact that this was not on the surface is disclaimed at the top of the post, the rest is lagely about why footage on the surface would be difficult and disappointing.

Answer (score 9):

The Lunar module had a habitable volume of 160 cubic foot (4.5 cubic metre). The crew compartment floor was about 36 by 55 inches (3 by 4.6 foot or 0.91 by 1.4 metre)

There was a [circuit breaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_11) damaged accidentally by Aldrin on Apollo 11. The breaker would arm the main engine for lift off from the Moon. So all later astronauts knew they had to behave slowly and carefully not to damage anything inside the small cabin.

See this [PDF](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/LM04_Lunar_Module_ppLV1-17.pdf) from NASA.

Comment: I ain't gonna try anything. And the question isn't on how much space in the LM is there but if there are videos of the astronauts inside the LM while it's on the Moon's surface.

Comment: well, your question was "Are there any videos of astronauts _walking_ inside ..." and we're pointing out there's no room to walk.

Comment: You removed walking/jumping from the body, but there is still a walking left in the title of the question.

Comment: I improved the question.

Comment: Can you cite your interior dimensions? They differ from [those found elsewhere](http://georgetyson.com/files/apollostatistics.pdf) and would necessitate a ceiling height of ~11.6ft, which seems excessive even without considering the entire ascent stage was ~12.3ft tall. The linked pdf gives numbers of approximately 3.5ft depth by 7.7ft height, which means the width must be ~6ft

Comment: @TemporalWolf: The link is there, see page 1 and 4 of this NASA [pdf](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/LM04_Lunar_Module_ppLV1-17.pdf).